# Getting filtered objects from url by passing correct attributes

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app with posts and comments with comments linked to the posts with foreign keys.
I am unable to fetch the comments for a particular post.

I checked my DB to make sure the foreign key is getting added correctly and it is. I tried changing the attribute name multiple times with no effect.

My html code in the post detail template for get all comments button is as below:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{url 'user-comments' object.id}">View Answers</a>
```

My views.py looks like this:

```
class PostCommentListView(ListView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'blog/comment.html'
    context_object_name = 'comments'
    ordering = ['-comment_date']
    paginate_by = 7

    def get_queryset(self):
        post = get_object_or_404(Comment, post_id=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))
        return Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-comment_date')
```

and the url 'user-comments' is as follows:

```
path('post/<int:post_id>', PostCommentListView.as_view(), name='user-comments')
```

I am getting a page not found message.

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/15/%7Burl%20'user-comments'%20object.id%7D

The current path, post/15/{url 'user-comments' object.id}, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your html page.

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{url 'user-comments' object.id}">View Answers</a>
```

This should be written as:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{% url 'user-comments' object.id %}">View Answers</a>
```

Please make sure you have properly maintained the syntax in your codes.

Answer (score 0):

In Django templates `url` should be called inside `{% %}` tags.

```
<a href="{% url 'user-comments' object.id %}">View Answers</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You url path should also have post id, which will show comments of one particular post.

```py
class PostCommentListView(ListView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'blog/comment.html'
    context_object_name = 'comments'
    ordering = ['-comment_date']
    paginate_by = 7

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(PostCommentListView, self).get_queryset()
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['post_id'])
        qs = qs.filter(post=post)
        return qs


## Then, in urls.py you should have your url path like this
path('posts/<int:post_id>/comments', views.PostCommentListView.as_view(),
         name='user-comments'),
```

In Django templates also, `url` should be called inside `{% %}` tags.

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{% url 'user-comments' object.id %}">View Answers</a>
```